# automatic created session values

Tags: python, django, error-handling

i have an code , whenever i use this code , it will automatically create session values like to print {{ user.username }} but now i make some changes and than the code is not working, it did not print the value {{ user.username }}.

views.py :_

```
import os ,sys
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout 
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from userprofile.forms import FuserRegistration,userLoginform
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .forms import UploadFileForm
from django.conf import settings

#Register function:
def userRegistration(request,template=None,context=None):
    #raise Exception(request)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FuserRegistration(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            authenticated_user=authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data["username"],password=form.cleaned_data["password"])
            login(request, authenticated_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/home/")
        else:

            template=u"registration/login.html"
            context = {"form": form}
            return render(request, template, context)
            #raise Exception(form.errors)
    else:

        form = FuserRegistration()
        template=u"registration/login.html"
        context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, template, context)



def userLogin(request,template=None,context=None):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = userLoginform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
#           authenticated_user = form.save()
#           login(request, authenticated_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/home/")
        else:
            template=u"registration/login.html"
            context= {"form": form}
            return render(request, template,context)
    else:
        form=userLoginform()
        template=u"registration/login.html"
        context= {"form": form}
    return render(request, template,context)


def userLogout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/login")



def home(request):
    return render_to_response(
    'home.html',
    { 'user': request.user }
    ) 


#@csrf_exempt

#def user_profile(request):
#   if request.method == 'POST':
#       form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
#       if form.is_multipart():
#           new_user = save_file(request.FILES['fileinput'])

#           return HttpResponse(new_user)
#       else:
#           return HttpResponse("form is not valid")
#   else:
#       form = ImageForm()
#       return render_to_response('user_profile.html', { 'form': form })


#   form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
#   if form.is_valid():
#            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
#            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_profileform/')
#   else:
#       return HttpResponse('1')
#   getusername = request.POST['username']
#   getfirstname = request.POST['first_name']
#   getemail =  request.POST['email']
#   if getusername != '' and getfirstname != '' and getemail !='':
#       try:    
#               getvalue = User.objects.get(username=getusername)

#               if getvalue:
#                   getvalue.username = getusername
#                   getvalue.first_name = getfirstname
#                   getvalue.email = getemail
#                   getvalue.save()
#                   userexist = "user exist"

#       except:
#               userexist = "Does not exist"
#   else:
#       userexist = "require field"
#       return HttpResponse(userexist)



def user_profileform(request):
    return render_to_response(
    'user_profile.html',
    { 'user': request.user }
    )


#function for rendering templates
def render(request, templates, dictionary=None, context_instance=None,
           **kwargs):
    """
    Mimics ``django.shortcuts.render`` but uses a TemplateResponse for
    ``mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForDeviceMiddleware``
    """
    dictionary = dictionary or {}
    if context_instance:
        context_instance.update(dictionary)
    else:
        context_instance = RequestContext(request, dictionary)
    return TemplateResponse(request, templates, context_instance, **kwargs)




@csrf_exempt
def upload_file(request):
    getfirstname = ''
    getusername = ''
    getemail = ''
    getpassword = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
    getusername = request.POST['username']
    getfirstname = request.POST['first_name']
    getemail =  request.POST['email']
    getpassword = request.POST['password']
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

#   if request.FILES['file'].name:
#       filename = request.FILES['file'].name
    for filename, file in request.FILES.iteritems():
        filename = request.FILES[filename].name
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
#            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_profileform/')
        getvalue = User.objects.get(username=getusername)
        getvalue.username = getusername
        getvalue.first_name = getfirstname
        getvalue.email = getemail
        getvalue.save()
        return render_to_response('user_profile.html', {'form': form, 'getusername': getusername,'getfirstname': getfirstname, 'getemail':getemail, 'getpassword':getpassword  })   
    else:

        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('user_profile.html', {'form': form })
@csrf_exempt
def handle_uploaded_file(f):

    destination = open('media/filename', 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks(): 
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

i want to print the value when user logged in than it should get the values from the login form and print the {{ user.username }}

Comment: `request.user.username` is probably what you want. It will contain the username of the logged in user.

Comment: Far too much code here. Please cut it down to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem.